# require exported typescript class in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, requirejs

I'm moving my nodejs project from Javascript to Typescript. It's going to be a slow process, slowly changing things over a few months as i need to tweak stuff.

I've created a typescript class that looks something like this:

```
// RedisRepository.ts

export class RedisRepository {
  public async getDevice(serial: string) : Promise<Device> {
    // blah
    return device;
  }
}
```

Then in another Javascript file where i need to reference and then call the functions on the above class.

```
// ExpressApi.js

const repository = require('../Redis/RedisRepository');

async function getRedis(req, res) {
  try {
    const device = await repository.getDevice('serialnumberxxx');
    res.status(200).end(JSON.stringify(device ));
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(e);
    res.status(500).end();
  }
}
```

however, when it tried to call the function on the repository it says it doesn't exist.  Using chrome debugger, i can see that it exists at: repository.RedisRepository.prototype.getDevice.  This doesn't seem the correct way to use the function though.

While I appreciate I could just convert ExpressApi.js to Typescript.  I'm going to have this problem with many different files. So i need to use it as JavaScript for now.  I'll slowly continue to go round the project and change things to Typescript.

Comment: Since `getDevice` is not `static`, you would need to `new RedisRepository` and then call `getDevice` on the instance.

Comment: You have export class so how about calling with import `import { RedisRepository } from '../Redis/RedisRepository'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @crashmstr mentioned, you should create a new instance of `RedisRepository`, then call `getDevice` method. 
If you still want to use

```
const repository = require('../Redis/RedisRepository');
```

syntax, you could `export default new RedisRepository()` from your `RedisRepository.ts` file.